# How to remove %0A from the url

Tags: php

```
<code> 
<form action="" method="get">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Check</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Check</th>
</tr>
<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='checkbox' onclick="check()" name='allowed' value='1' <?
$reflex=mysql_query("select distinct * from geocity where isAllowed='1' AND 
country='" . $row['Code'] . "'"); $count = mysql_num_rows($reflex); if ($count ==
1{echo 'checked';}else{echo '';} ?>>
</td>
<td><? echo $row['CountryName']; ?></td>
<td>
<input type='checkbox' id="check1" name='countryname' value="<?echo $row['Code'];?>"
<? $reflex = mysql_query("select distinct * from geocity where isAllowed='1' AND 
country='" . $row['Code'] . "'"); $count = mysql_num_rows($reflex); if ($count == 1)
{echo 'checked';}else{echo '';} ?>>
</td>
</tr>
<?
};
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" class='button' value="Save">
</form>
</code>
```

Here is my code but when i submit the for the problem occurs is that in the url "%0A" this occurs so how can I remove this %0A from the url.
the url looks something like this:
    `example.com/test.php?allowed=1&countryname=AF%0A`

Comment: `%0A` is a percent-encoded newline character.

Comment: The bigger question is why you would get that encoding in the first place.  The country code should be just two alpha characters and looking at the above it doesn't seem like a newline would be introduced in the form, so my guess is that the newline actually exists in the database entry for `Code` and should be cleaned up.

Answer (score 5):

The `%0A` is an url encoded character.
To remove them in PHP, use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function.

[ADD]
If you want to remove adding spaces (you have some here : **value="AF "**), use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function in the `echo` treatment.

And review your database content to remove spaces with [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) like this :

```
UPDATE countries set countryname = TRIM(countryname);
```

Comment: Ok, what's the problem? The GET params are automatically encoded in URL form. It's for compatibility reason.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you need to clean the `Code` field in your database to limit it to two characters.  Run this on your DB to clean up the data:

```
UPDATE geocity
SET Code = SUBSTRING(Code, 1, 2);
```

This is of course assuming that the first two characters for that field in each record are the two correct fields and that any newline characters present in the data come after those.

It should also be noted that your database access pattern could be greatly improved. You are running the same query twice within a loop. And if this is a loop through hundreds of country codes, you could be making hundreds of DB queries when you only need a single one.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP use the following code:

```
 $string = str_replace("%0A"," ","text%0Amore");
```